# How to show date and time on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, x-axis

I would like to assign for x axis in matplotlib plot full date with time but with autoscale I could get only times or dates but not both.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range('2015-10-06', periods=500, freq='10min')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(times, range(times.size))
plt.show()
```

And on x axis I get only times without any dates so it's hard to distinct measurements.

I think that it's some option in matplotlib in matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter but I couldn't find any one that could allow me to change that autoscale.

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this with a [`matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter), which takes a [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/) format string as its argument. To get a `day-month-year hour:minute` format, you can use `%d-%m-%y %H:%M`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

times = pd.date_range('2015-10-06', periods=500, freq='10min')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(times, range(times.size))

xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you define two y-axis for your plot, you may need to call `xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)` on the other axis object.

Comment: how can we increase the number of dates (the frequency of showing the dates) on the x-axis?

Comment: @Nihat you would want to change the `Locator`. For example, in this case we could use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=6))` to have a tick every 6 hours. See [the docs here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers) for a list of different available locators.

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.figure() 
plt.plot(...)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() plt.show()
```

Comment: Adding context to a code answer is considered useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to plot date and time column when it is not your index column.
`fig, ax = plt.subplots() ax.plot('docdate', 'count', data=newdf) fig.autofmt_xdate() plt.show()`

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: This is just a very simplified version of accepted answer with no real addition.