# Convert datetime to time in python

Tags: python

I have:

```
test_date = "2017-07-20-10-30"
```

and then use:

```
day = datetime.strptime(test_date[11:], "%H-%M")
```

which gives me

```
1900-01-01 10:30:00
```

How do I just get: `10:30:00` as type `datetime.time`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `strftime` method of the `datetime` object like this:

```
day.strftime('%H:%M')
```

More information here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Ok, I misunderstood. Use `day.time()` to get a `time` object.

Comment: But this returns string. I still want <type 'datetime.time'>

Comment: oh, use `day.time()`

Comment: What if I have a Pandas Series of datetime objects and I want time?

Comment: I wanted the above for time-only tick labels in matplotlib plots, which can be achieved as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32973263/1386750).

Answer (score 3):

you can parse your string using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime) to a `datetime` object and then call [`.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) on that to get the time:

```
from datetime import datetime

strg = "2017-07-20-10-30"

dt = datetime.strptime(strg, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
tme = dt.time()
print(tme)  # 10:30:00
```

the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is well documented.

of course you can also chain these calls:

```
tme = datetime.strptime(strg, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M').time()
```