# How to manage overlapping of dates in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series

I have a dataset- pandas dataframe. I am trying to plot a graph using matplotlib. For example

[image: Sample input]

The data is sorted based on date from oldest to newest. The date is on x-axis and "Total_Repeats" is on y-axis.

I am using the following code to produce the graph

```
plt.plot(ts)
```

[image: sample output]

It can be seen that the dates in x-axis is overlapping a lot. I would like to see the dates properly. May be in month-wise format such as **Jan-2018**,**Feb-2018**,**March-2018** etc. I am not sure how to format. Kindly share some thoughts.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Do not put the dataframe as an image, but as something that can be reproduced.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32973263) answer maybe help.

Comment: I managed to solve the error. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score -1):

if you have your data in a `pd.DataFrame` the easiest thing to do is to rotate the labels

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='05/08/2018' )
values = np.random.rand(128)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, dates)
df.plot(rot=90)
```

[image]