# Adding a vertical line to a time series plot in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

I used the answer to this question to try and add a vertical line to my time series plot: [How do you plot a vertical line on a time series plot in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213789/how-do-you-plot-a-vertical-line-on-a-time-series-plot-in-pandas)

This is my code:

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(12,8), logy=True, title='Random Forest Regressor Performance',\
                 color={'price': 'blue', 'count': 'orange', 'pred': 'green'})

ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2021-08-23'), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
```

And this is my data (I set the date (datetime) as an index):

| date | price | pred | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 13657.20 | 12671.454 | 89709 |
| 2018-01-02 | 14982.10 | 18561.360 | 125144 |
| 2018-01-03 | 15201.00 | 14437.636 | 134138 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-10-30 | 61888.10 | 39418.360 | 283597 |
| 2021-10-31 | 61318.00 | 34461.636 | 312403 |

In my case, using this method results in the line being put way out of the actual data. The idea is to put the line to this graph. What I get:

[image: plot with line]

Expected Result:

[image: time series plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that pandas does not set the axis format to date time, but converts the date-time values to number and changes the tick labels. Explicitly creating the axis and setting the correct format works.

Following this [accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972371/how-to-show-date-and-time-on-x-axis-in-matplotlib), the minimal example below shows how to set the date-time format of the axis and add the hline by using a corresponding date-time string.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range('2021-12-07', periods=500, freq='D')
yvalues = range(times.size)

df = pd.DataFrame(yvalues, times)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.axvline(pd.to_datetime('2023-01-23'), color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
ax = df.plot(ax=ax, title='Random Forest Regressor Performance')
plt.show()
```

Which results in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmusE.png)